# On large JSON strings only in Ajax request, getting MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter '..' is not present

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, datatables

The following code works 90% of the time on normal-length JSON strings. I receive an incoming JSON String in my SpringMVC Controller, formed from a DataTable `.data()`.

Ajax:

```
function exportParticipants() {
    var table = $('#participantsTable').DataTable();
    var displayData = table.rows({filter:'applied'}).data(); // Get my data into "result" array
    var result = $.makeArray();
    $.each(displayData,function(index,row) {
        result.push(row);
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/app/loadParticipantsExportValues",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            'participants': JSON.stringify(result)  // Note that I form this 'participants' param
        },
        success: function (res){
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error");
        }
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loadParticipantsExportValues", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void loadParticipantsExportValues(@RequestParam("participants") String json) throws Exception {
   //...
}
```

But on very large JSON strings only (formed from a 10K-row DataTable), even though I verify in the Debugger that the array gets created, I get this:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'participants' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
```

Any ideas? Is something getting truncated or maxed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It was a Tomcat `maxPostSize` issue, the default value is 2MB.

Example of what fixed it, **server.xml in Tomcat**:

```
<Connector port="8009" maxPostSize="4000000" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

or, unlimited:

```
<Connector port="8009" maxPostSize="-1" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490643/1005607

Answer (score 2):

Many clients truncate large Request parameter --> [limit on query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091485/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring-get-url-parameters)

Please use `@RequestBody` as in

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loadParticipantsExportValues", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void loadParticipantsExportValues(@RequestBody String participants) throws Exception{

    //....
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately same problem on big strings, only this time it's: `HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing`. It works for small strings, but not for large ones.

Comment: `HttpMessageNotReadableException` means it is not able to understand the json. Why dont you try making `@RequestBody String participants` instead and then use some mapper to convert it into pojos

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried as well. I think it's a DataTable issue.